# Ruby on Rails: How to show the image title? (Edited)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to show the image title above the image after redirecting to user profile. I upload an image with a title and it only shows the image with the tags and user. I tried by adding the code in show.html.haml below but the title doesn't show at all. What I am doing wrong?

photos_controller.rb

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    if params[:photo][:title] == ""
      flash[:alert] = "Please enter an image title"
      redirect_to :back
    elsif params[:photo][:image] == nil
      flash[:alert] = "Please upload a photo"
      redirect_to :back
    else
      @photo = Photo.create(photo_params)
      @photo.user_id = @user.id
      @photo.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully uploaded a photo"
      redirect_to user_path(@user)
    end
  end

  def new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @photo = Photo.create()
  end

  private
  def photo_params
    params.require(:photo).permit(:image, :title)
  end
end
```

photo.rb

```
class Photo<ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :tags
  
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  validates :title, :presence => true
end
```

20150318211456_photos_table.rb

```
class PhotosTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :photos do |photons|
      photons.column :user_id, :integer
      photons.column :title, :string
      photons.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

new.html.haml

```
%h1 Add a Photo
= form_for Photo.new(), :url => user_photos_path, :html => {:multipart => true} do |form|
    = form.label :title
    = form.text_field :title
    %br
    %br
    = form.file_field :image
    %br
    %br
    %br
    = form.submit 'Upload', class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg"
```

show.html.haml

```
= link_to @user_photos_path do
    = @photo.title
    = image_tag @photo.image.url
    = image_tag @photo.image.url(:thumb)
```

Comment: you don't have a `title` column in your photos table or are you going to use `caption`?

Comment: I am going to use caption

Answer (score 0):

You can add a field for `:caption` just like you've done with `:image`:

```rb
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @photo = Photo.new() # don't create the photo yet
  end

  private
  def photo_params
    params.require(:photo).permit(:image, :caption) # allow caption field
  end
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<h1>Add a Photo</h1>
<%= form_for Photo.new(), :url => user_photos_path, :html => {:multipart => true} do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :caption %>
  <%= form.file_field :image %>
  <%= form.submit 'Upload'%>
<% end %>
```

show.html.erb

```
<p><%= @photo.caption %></p>
<%= image_tag @photo.image.url %>
<%= image_tag @photo.image.url(:thumb) %>
```

Comment: Gives me an error: private method `initialize' called for #<Class:0x00007f67d9bb1ca8>

Comment: You can use `Photo.new` instead of `Photo.initialize`, just don't use `Photo.create` as that tries to create and save the record.

Comment: `#initialize` is not a class method - its a hook thats called when you call the `.new` method. You should edit the question and fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt is creative but it doesn't really have anything to do with how you actually do CRUD in Rails:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos
end
```

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_user

  # POST /users/1/photos
  def create
    @photo = @user.photos.new(photo_params)
    if @photo.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully uploaded a photo"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  # GET /users/1/photos/new
  def new
    @photo = @user.photos.new
  end

  private

  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  end

  def photo_params
    params.require(:photo)
          .permit(:image, :caption)
  end
end
```

You are confusing the `Photo.new` method which is used to initialize new instances in memory and the `Photo.create` method which will also save the record in the database - you don't want to do that in the `new` method in your controller.

`if params[:photo] == nil` is pointless. `params.require(:photo)` will raise a `ActionController::ParameterMissing` exception is the parameter is not present. If you want to ensure that the user has uploaded a photo or that the caption is present you [use validations in your model](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html).

What you're not checking is the one thing thats actually important - that the record is actually valid and was saved in the DB.

Use `form_with` instead of the older `form_for` which is slated for eventual deprechiation and bind the form to the model instance you create in your controller:

```
<h1>Add a Photo</h1>
<%= form_with model: [@user, @photo], html: { multipart: true} do |form| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :image %>
    <%= form.file_field :image %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :caption %>
    <%= form.text_field :caption %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit 'Upload'%>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

That way the form will retain the user input when there is an invalid form submission. Thats why you call `render :new` instead of `redirect_to :back`. The later also doesn't actually work in case the client doesn't send a HTTP_REFERRER header (in other words don't use it).

Comment: I get this error in new.html.haml: uninitialized constant Photo::Caption

Comment: @SeraFM oops. There was a little copy-pasta bug in the form - should have been `form.text_field :caption` instead of `form.text_field :image`. Edited.

Comment: Yes I noticed that

Comment: `uninitialized constant Photo::Caption` sounds like you have a typo where you used `Caption` instead of `:caption`.

Comment: https://ibb.co/Wvm7ZV3 here is a screenshot

Comment: Do you have a stack trace?  I'm guessing the error occurs somewhere inside the `#caption` method of Photo.

Comment: I don't have a caption method.

Comment: Hey. The only problem now is that the title is not showing after the upload

Comment: Write an integration test where you fill in the form and submit it and then look at `Photo.last.caption` and see if the error is if you're not saving the value or if its that you're not fetching the record you think. I can't hand hold you on every step of the way since I can't actually see the code you're working on. You need to grasp the actual concepts involved and be able to debug your own code.